# VSCode Debugging local github fork in project using this fork

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, pip

I am working on projectA (which is a folder on my local machine) in VSCode (on macOS) and i have installed projectB (also a folder on my local machine) in the virtual environment of projectA using `pip install -e path_to_projectB` so that changes i make to projectB are immediately active and i don't need to reinstall anything.

I have a script in projectA called `my_script.py`, that uses an installed module of projectB and i want to debug that imported module within the run of `my_script.py`.
However, breakpoints i have set on projectB are not catched by VSCode.

My launch.json file (of projectA) looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "python: my_script",
     "type": "python",
     "request": "launch",
     "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/my_script.py",
     "console": "integratedTerminal",
     "justMyCode": false,
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "installed projectB" ?   have you made a new folder or done a `pip install` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have installed a projectB (which is on a new folder on my local machine) using pip install -e into the virtual environment i am using in projectA

My problem is, that VSCode does not stop at breakpoints, which i set in python files on projectB, when i launch a script from projectA (although the script from projectA uses projectB, which means that the code of ProjectB runs for sure).

Comment: See the link and then edit your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VSCode to find breakpoints in projectB, it must be added to the workspace of projectA:

1. Open projectA in VSCode
2. Right click inside the file browser and select "Add folder to workspace..." and add the folder of projectB
3. Add breakpoints at the desired positions in projectB, by opening the files from projectB within this newly created workspace.

Now, when running `my_script.py` the breakpoints you set in projectB will stop the run as expected.
In `launch.json` `"justMyCode"` can also stay true.

My problem was that I had both folders open in a separate VSCode window. This way the breakpoints of projectB did not stop the run of `my_script.py`.